# TYCHO maven build is including two differents org.slf4j.api versions

Tags: eclipse, logback, slf4j, tycho, slf4j-api

I'm using org.slf4j and ch.qos.logback to log my osgi application, designed and executed under eclipse equinox environnement.
everything works well.
The SLF4J plugin is declared once,in a feature file, as follow:

```
<plugin
      id="org.slf4j.api"
      download-size="0"
      install-size="0"
      version="0.0.0"
      unpack="false"/>
```

When I run the application under the eclipse debugger, or when I export the application under the eclipse product export feature, my logs are correctly handled accordingly with the logback.xml.

When I look in the myapp/plugin folder, I find these 2 jars:
 - org.slf4j.api_1.7.2.v20121108-1250.jar
 - org.slf4j.log4j_1.7.2.v20130115-1340.jar

**But**, when I build the application with TYCHO and MAVEN, I find 2 different versions of org.slf4j.api in the myapp/plugins/ folder:

- org.slf4j.api_1.7.2.v20121108-1250.jar
- **org.slf4j.api_1.7.10.v20160921-1923.jar**
- org.slf4j.log4j_1.7.2.v20130115-1340.jar

as a result, when I execute the application, the following message is displayed:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
osgi> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

It looks like the org.slf4j.api_1.7.10 jar is included in the build and breaks the logging mechanism.

This breaks my automatic build.

Please help.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I'm not using target files.
In the main pom file, I've set 2 repositories:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipse</id>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon</url>
            <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>orbit</id>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20160520211859/repository/</url>
            <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found where the issue was:

p2 repositories are incompatibles.
I've synchronized URLs and now it's ok.

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipse</id>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon</url>
            <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>orbit</id>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/R-builds/R20170307180635/repository/</url>
            <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

@Andreas: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that your product (I assume it’s a feature-based product) contains a feature which pulls in `org.slf4j.api` version 1.7.2 and another feature which pulls in 1.7.10. (Well, theoretically the same feature could bull both versions in, but that’s rare.)

If you are using a `.target` definition file in your Tycho build, I good first shot at identifying how two versions of `org.slf4j.api` end up in your target platform is opening the file in the *Target Editor*, switching to the *Content* tab, and selecting *Group by* *Location*. This tells you which update site the `org.slf4j.api` 1.7.10 comes from (but not the exact feature). If you have narrowed things down to a feature, you can try search for a replacement that does not contain the offending `org.slf4j.api` bundle.

Comment: Hi,Thank youfor your answer, but I'm not using .target files, but p2 repositories as described in my post latest edit.

Comment: Got it. Your `eclipse` repository contains `org.slf4j.api` in both version 1.7.2 and 1.7.10 (Tip: to check this yourself, you can go to the *Repository Explorer* view, enable *Expert Mode* and search for an *osgi.bundle* named `org.slf4j.api`). In all likelihood, on the the features available from that site is re-used by you in your product and requires version 1.7.10. What features are in your product? (You can open the .`product` file in a text editor and paste the relevant portion here.)